# django using the primary key that was created to insert data into another table

Tags: django

I have 2 table. `Schedule` and `BookAppt`. After creating the schedule, i want to use the scheduleId that was create to be insert as one of the field in BookAppt. However my method has this error.

`File "C:\Django project\AppImmuneMe2\customuser\views.py", line 62, in my_django_view
    schedule = data['save1.scheduleId']
KeyError: 'save1.scheduleId'`

May i know what is wrong ?

```
    # Create a schedule
    user = data['patientId']
    userId = MyUser.objects.get(userId=user)

    save_attrs_schedule = {
        "userId": userId,
        "date": data["date"],
        "startTime": data["time"],
        "endTime": end_time,
        "status": data["status"],
    }
    save1 = Schedule.objects.create(**save_attrs_schedule)

    # Create a BookAppt with schedule that was just created as foreign key
    patient = data['patientId']
    patientId = MyUser.objects.get(userId=patient)
    schedule = data['save1.scheduleId']
    scheduleId = Schedule.objects.get(scheduleId=schedule)

    saveget_attrs_bookappt = {
        "patientId": patientId,
        "clinicId": data["clinicId"],
        "date": data["date"],
        "time": data["time"],
        "scheduleId": scheduleId,
    }
    save2 = BookAppt.objects.create(**saveget_attrs_bookappt)
```

**model**

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    scheduleId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    startTime = models.TimeField()
    endTime = models.TimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    # reminder
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class BookAppt(models.Model):
    clinicId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    patientId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheduleId = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheduleTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    ticketNo = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**view**

```
class ScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer

class BookApptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = BookAppt.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookApptSerializer
```

**stacktrace**

`[05/Feb/2018 17:27:03] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 139
Internal Server Error: /api/bookapp/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 706, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 679, in get_context
    'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 509, in get_rendered_html_form
    return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 519, in render_form_for_serializer
    {'style': {'template_pack': 'rest_framework/horizontal'}}
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 371, in render
    return template_render(template, context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\compat.py", line 340, in template_render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 203, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 91, in render_field
    return renderer.render_field(field, style)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 350, in render_field
    return template_render(template, context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\compat.py", line 340, in template_render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 166, in render
    values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 209, in iter_options
    self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 196, in get_choices
    for item in queryset
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 196, in <listcomp>
    for item in queryset
  File "C:\Users\Baka No Onii Chan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 215, in display_value
    return six.text_type(instance)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
[05/Feb/2018 17:27:24] "GET /api/bookapp/ HTTP/1.1" 500 244570`

Answer (score 1):

```
schedule = save1.id
scheduleId = Schedule.objects.get(scheduleId=schedule)
```

just use this

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.clinicId
```

add this line to your BookApt Model

Comment: But this has cause my BookAppt api to have this error `TypeError at /api/bookapp/
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`

Comment: where is your render for that view? or redirect statement?

Comment: where is the part you asked at the beginning getting error is written?

Comment: im using the router ulr for the api. So the schedule api website works but when going into the bookappt api website, it just give me that error

Comment: can you post the stacktrace, full

Comment: Updated. Is that the stacktrace?